# store 300 digit number in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

Which datatype can I use to store really big integer in SQL. I am using phpmyAdmin to view data and java program for storing and retrieving values. Actually I am working with Bilinear Maps which uses random numbers generated from Zp where p is very large prime number and then "raised to" operations on those number.

I want to store some numbers in database like public keys. What data type can I use for table columns in SQL for such values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store them as strings of decimal digits using type `CHARACTER`. While this does waste some space, an advantage is that the database will be easier for humans to understand.

You could store them as raw binary big-endian values using type `BLOB`. This is the most efficient for software to access and takes up the least space. However, humans will not be able to easily query the database for these values or understand them in dumps.

Personally, I would opt for the blob unless there's a real need for the database to be understandable by humans using standard query tools. If you can't get around needing to administer the database with tools that don't understand your data format, then just use decimal values in text.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, `VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET ascii`.

- `VAR`, assuming the numbers won't always be exactly 300.
- `CHAR` -- no big advantage in `BLOB`.
- `ascii` -- no need for utf8 involvement.
- `DECIMAL` won't work because there is a 64-digit limit.

The space taken will be 2+length bytes (302 in your example), where the 2 is for length for `VAR`.